# Vue.js: attempting to fadeOut() one image and fadeIn() another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fadein, fadeout

This working bit of code (assuming foo/foo_ad1.jpg thru foo/foo_ad11.jpg is loaded on server) loads a random picture from a bank of pictures, and replaces it with another picture every few seconds.

I'm trying to get the pictures to gracefully fade in and out, and that's where I'm running into two issues:

1) I can't get 'this.image' to display when I move it into the setTimeOut function.

2) I wasn't able to get the fadeIn() or fadeOut() working, I'm not even sure what the correct syntax would be.

Please see the comments added in the code. TY

JS:

```
Vue.component('foo-ad-module', {
    data() {
        return {
            image:  'foo/foo_ad1.jpg',
            timer:  '',
            x:          0
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        this.replaceImage();
        this.timer = setInterval(this.replaceImage, parseInt((Math.random() * 33599)%30000) + 5000)
    },  
    methods: {
        init(){
            this.x = parseInt((Math.random() * 33599)%11) + 1;
              this.image = 'foo/foo_ad' + this.x + '.jpg';
              console.info("this.image = " + this.image);
       },
       replaceImage: function() {
            this.x = parseInt((Math.random() * 33599)%11) + 1;
//#if
           this.image = 'foo/foo_ad' + this.x + '.jpg';     // ...THIS WORKS (when it is outside the setTimeout())
//#else
//          $(???).fadeOut("2000");                                     // ... intending to put a fadeOut() here...
            setTimeout(function () {        
                console.info("this is working...");                                                          
//              this.image = 'foo/foo_ad' + this.x + '.jpg';    // ... THIS DOESN'T WORK (when it is inside the setTimeout())
//              $(???).fadeIn("2000");                                  //  ... intending to put a fadeIn() here...                                         
            }, 2000);
//#endif            

            clearInterval(this.timer)         
        this.timer = setInterval(this.replaceImage, (parseInt((Math.random() * 33599)%30000) + 5000));        
       },
  },
    beforeDestroy() {
      clearInterval(this.timer)
    },  
    mounted(){
        this.init()
    },  
    template: `
                <div class="foo-ad-module " >
               <img :src="image" alt="hi there">
                </div>  `
});
```

CSS:

```
.foo-ad-module {
    width:          198px;
    height:         198px;
    border:         1px solid #555;     
    border-radius:  10px;
    margin-bottom:  10px;
}
```

Comment: Allow me to clarify a little on #1: the problem is that when the this.image is moved to be within the setTimeout, it has no effect -- the picture stays on the original image, and does not update.

Answer (score 0):

### `setTimeout` context

The context is not properly set in `setTimeout(function() {});`, so `this` is not your Vue component within the timer callback. If your project allows ES6, you could use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to fix the issue:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.image = '...';
}, 2000);
```

On the other hand, if you could only use ES5, you'd have to use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to fix the issue:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  this.image = '...';
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

...or pass in a reference to `this`:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
  self.image = '...';
}, 2000);
```

### Fading image

You could use Vue's [`<transition>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components) to fade the `<img>`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      show: true
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle image
  </button>
  <div>
    <transition name="fade">
      <img v-if="show" src="//placekitten.com/100/100" alt="kitten">
    </transition>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solved both the issues. Thank You! Specifically, the bind, and the transition as in your example work together like a charm.

Comment: @user3213769 No problem :)